# How to determine if Write-Host will work for the current host

Tags: powershell, write-host, powershell-hosting

Is there any sane, reliable contract that dictates whether `Write-Host` is supported in a given PowerShell host implementation, in a script that could be run against any reasonable host implementation?

(Assume that I understand the difference between `Write-Host` and `Write-Output`/`Write-Verbose` and that I definitely do want `Write-Host` semantics, if supported, for this specific human-readable text.)

I thought about trying to interrogate the `$Host` variable, or `$Host.UI`/`$Host.UI.RawUI` but the only pertinent differences I am spotting are:

- in `$Host.Name`:

  - The Windows powershell.exe commandline has `$Host.Name = 'ConsoleHost'`
  - ISE has `$Host.Name = 'Windows PowerShell ISE Host'`
  - SQL Server Agent job steps have `$Host.Name = 'Default Host'`
  - I have none of the non-Windows versions installed, but I expect they are different
- in `$Host.UI.RawUI`:

  - The Windows powershell.exe commandline returns values for all properties of `$Host.UI.RawUI`
  - ISE returns no value (or `$null`) for some properties of `$Host.UI.RawUI`, e.g. `$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorSize`
  - SQL Server Agent job steps return no values for all of `$Host.UI.RawUI`
  - Again, I can't check in any of the other platforms

Maintaining a list of `$Host.Name` values that support `Write-Host` seems like it would be bit of a burden, especially with PowerShell being cross-platform now.  I would reasonably want the script to be able to be called from any host and just *do the right thing*.

### Background

I have written a script that can be reasonably run from within the PowerShell command prompt, from within the ISE or from within a SQL Server Agent job.  The output of this script is entirely textual, for human reading.  When run from the command prompt or ISE, the output is colorized using `Write-Host`.

SQL Server jobs can be set up in two different ways, and both support capturing the output into the SQL Server Agent log viewer:

1. via a CmdExec step, which is simple command-line execution, where the Job Step command text is an executable and its arguments, so you invoke the powershell.exe executable.  Captured output is the stdout/sterr of the process:

   ```
   powershell.exe -Command x:\pathto\script.ps1 -Arg1 -Arg2 -Etc
   ```
2. via a PowerShell step, where the Job Step command text is raw PS script interpreted by its own embedded PowerShell host implementation.  Captured output is whatever is written via `Write-Output` or `Write-Error`:

   ```
   #whatever
   Do-WhateverPowershellCommandYouWant
   x:\pathto\script.ps1 -Arg1 -Arg2 -Etc
   ```

Due to some other foibles of the SQL Server host implementation, I find that you can emit output using either `Write-Output` or `Write-Error`, but not both.  If the job step fails (i.e. if you `throw` or `Write-Error 'foo' -EA 'Stop'`), you *only* get the error stream in the log and, if it succeeds, you only get the output stream in the log.

Additionally, the embedded PS implementation does not support `Write-Host`.  Up to at least SQL Server 2016, `Write-Host` throws a `System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException` with the message *A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction*.

To support all of my use-cases, so far, I took to using a custom function `Write-Message` which was essentially set up like (simplified):

```
 $script:can_write_host = $true
 $script:has_errors = $false
 $script:message_stream = New-Object Text.StringBuilder

 function Write-Message {
     Param($message, [Switch]$iserror)

     if ($script:can_write_host) {
         $private:color = if ($iserror) { 'Red' } else { 'White' }
         try { Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor $private:color }
         catch [Management.Automation.Host.HostException] { $script:can_write_host = $false }
     }
     if (-not $script:can_write_host) {
         $script:message_stream.AppendLine($message) | Out-Null
     }
     if ($iserror) { $script:has_errors = $true }
 }

 try { 
     <# MAIN SCRIPT BODY RUNS HERE #>
 }
 catch { 
     Write-Message -Message ("Unhandled error: " + ($_ | Format-List | Out-String)) -IsError
 }
 finally {
     if (-not $script:can_write_host) {
         if ($script:has_errors) { Write-Error ($script:message_stream.ToString()) -EA 'Stop' }
         else { Write-Output ($script:message_stream.ToString()) }
     }
 }
```

As of SQL Server 2019 (perhaps earlier), it appears `Write-Host` no longer throws an exception in the embedded SQL Server Agent PS host, but is instead a no-op that emits nothing to either output or error streams.  Since there is no exception, my script's `Write-Message` function can no longer reliably detect whether it should use `Write-Host` or `StringBuilder.AppendLine`.

The basic workaround for SQL Server Agent jobs is to use the more-mature CmdExec step type (where `Write-Output` and `Write-Host` both get captured as stdout), but I do prefer the PowerShell step type for (among other reasons) its ability to split the command reliably across multiple lines, so I am keen to see if there is a more-holistic, PowerShell-based approach to solve the problem of whether `Write-Host` does anything useful for the host I am in.

Comment: PowerShell output coloring feels like a feature that was tacked on, then neglected. Workarounds (not solutions) that I can think of: 1)  use `$Host.Name` to detect known scenarios where Write-Host is supported, default to Write-Output in other cases; 2) use a switch to specify whether to use Write-Host and coloration, and rely on the caller to specify mode

Comment: @Tydaeus :: Indeed, so far, the Switch parameter is the only reliable way I've come across.  In most of my scripts, now, I have replaced the `$script:can_write_host = $true` with `$script:can_write_host = (-not $BufferOutput)`, where *BufferOutput* is a Switch parameter.

Comment: Jeffrey Snover told us back in 2013 to stop using Write-Host all together :) [Write-Host Considered Harmful](https://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)

Comment: @Dennis :: until a viable alternative for colourised, human-readable, non-pipelined output exists, I suspect most people aren't going to care

Comment: Well, if you want non-pipelined output, then Write-Host is the cmdlet for you... But once you start writing Advanced Functions, that is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if your host is UserInteractive or an service type environment.

```
$script:can_write_host = [Environment]::UserInteractive
```

Comment: Have a +1 for informing me about `[Environment]::UserInteractive`.  I'll test this shortly.  *After two years of looking, it can't be that simple, can it...?*

Comment: Yeah sure i thought you might be on the total wrong track searching the answer inside this $Host Variables. I use this [Environment]::UserInteractive inside powershell script to determinate if the .ps1 is run by a task scheduler (SYSTEM). And the Task scheduler is a kind of service like the Job Agent.

Comment: I think it's something that solves my *actual* problem, but not necessarily the problem *as described in the title*; i.e. I might be able use it to differentiate between PS/ISE usage and SQL Agent usage; but it doesn't actually determine if `Write-Host` would fail.  For my use-case, it is very likely to be good enough (hence the +1) but, *technically* one can still schedule `cmd /s /c "powershell -command "Write-Host 'test'" > out.txt"` and, while `[Environment]::UserInteractive` would return `$false`, `Write-Host` calls would still work.

Comment: Maybe this article can be helpful https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/ as you stated correctly Write-Host uses the default of the underlying PSHost

Answer (score 0):

Another way to track the output of a script in real time is to push that output to a log file and then monitor it in real time using trace32. This is just a workaround, but it might work out for you.

```
Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\username\Documents\PS_log.log" -Value $variablewithvalue
```